# JS $('x').myfunction is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am ciruious to know what are the reasons that could cause a function "not being" one.
For example, I have the following:

```
$.fn.myfunction = function(options){
  alert("test");
};
  $("#hello").myfunction();
alert($.fn.myfunction instanceof Function);
```

Why would FireBug, log that it is not a function?

Thanks in advance.

**Edit:**
I would like a list of all the possibilities that could be the reason for the error.
This isn't an error I got, but I just want to widen my perspective and be aware of more possibilities.

Comment: Maybe `$` in `$('x').myfunction` refers to another function than `$` in `$.fn.myfunction`.

Comment: Log what is not a function where? Please, more information.

Comment: Has jQuery been loaded already?

Comment: Can you give us some simple test code we can run, showing that `myVar instanceof Function` returns false?

Comment: @AymanSafadi Yes. apsillers - i've added some code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Setting `$.fn.myfunction` makes the `myfunction` function available to the object returned by `$(selector)`, not to `$` itself.

Thus, `$("#hello").myfunction` is a function but `$.myfunction` is not.  If you really want `$.myfunction` to be a function for some reason (e.g., it's a utility function that doesn't need a jQuery object list to operate), just set it explicitly, without using `$.fn`:

```
$.myfunction = function() { .... }
```

Comment: It's the difference between [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) and [`$.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/). Both are totally different functions.

Comment: Here's a great article explaining this in more detail: http://asimilia.wordpress.com/2008/12/17/jquery-extend-confusion/

Answer (score 2):

What is `$` in the context? jQuery perhaps? If it´s jQuery you´re using, please tag your question as such.

```
(function( $ ) {
  $.fn.myPlugin = function() {

    return this.each(function() { // Maintaining chainability

      var $this = $(this);

      // Do your awesome plugin stuff here
      console.log($this); // TEMP

    });

  };
})( jQuery );
```

Usage: `$('#hello').myPlugin();`

See more information about [jQuery plugin authoring](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring).

Answer (score 1):

adding parentheses seemed to work:

```
alert($().myfunction instanceof Function);
```

returns true.